# ListHeader in Zk binding

Tags: java, data-binding, zk, zk-grid

I have an issue   loading dates in a listheader in zk.But i need load the same data in each day of the week, in my case the variable `loadData` is a List of Strings with two camps:  {"atr1", "atr2"}, can anyone give me any idea

code:

```
<zk>
    <div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('campaign.Campaign')">
        <window id="usersEdit">
            <listbox>
                <auxhead>
                    <auxheader colspan="2" class="topic">Lunes</auxheader>
                    <auxheader colspan="2" class="topic">Martes</auxheader>
                    <auxheader colspan="2" class="topic">Miercoles</auxheader>
                    <auxheader colspan="2" class="topic">Jueves</auxheader>
                    <auxheader colspan="2" class="topic">Viernes</auxheader>
                    <auxheader colspan="2" class="topic">Sabado</auxheader>
                    <auxheader colspan="2" class="topic">Domingo</auxheader>
                </auxhead>
                <listhead children="@load(vm.loadData)">
                    <template name="children" var="headerName">
                        <listheader label="@load(headerName)" sort="auto"></listheader>
                        <listheader label="@load(headerName)" sort="auto"></listheader>
                        <listheader label="@load(headerName)" sort="auto"></listheader>
                        <listheader label="@load(headerName)" sort="auto"></listheader>
                        <listheader label="@load(headerName)" sort="auto"></listheader>
                        <listheader label="@load(headerName)" sort="auto"></listheader>
                        <listheader label="@load(headerName)" sort="auto"></listheader>
                    </template>
                </listhead>
            </listbox>
        </window>
    </div>
</zk>
```

The problem is that i  have not the same data in columns  for each day of the week.

I need something like this:

```
  lunes       martes       Miercoles      Jueves       Viernes       Sabado
atr1  atr2   atr1  atr2   atr1  atr2    atr1  atr2    atr1  atr2   atr1  atr2 ...
```

The problem is the listheader sort  by name of my columns, and i have something like this:

```
  lunes       martes       Miercoles      Jueves       Viernes       Sabado
atr1  atr1   atr1  atr1   atr1  atr1    atr2  atr2    atr2  atr2   atr2  atr2 ...
```

but How can i resolve my issue, because i need load of a list, because the list is a query in my database.

Comment: Show us How to create loadData List i mean to say add java code as well?

Comment: I am using somithing like: http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3op451q/12-Dynamic-Columns

Comment: So the result which is coming after running fiddle demo is wrong ? If yes what type of result you want? Its look ok to me because u set data in same manner.